# JMeter treating "${COOKIE_[cookiename]}" as a string

Tags: jmeter

I have looked at numerous examples of setting properties from cookies, and they all seem to be indicate that using a BeanShell PostProcessor, I should be able to do the following, given a cookie named 'FOO'.

```
props.put( "fooCookie", "${COOKIE_FOO}" );
```

However, when I try to write that value to the console, as you see here...

```
print( props.get( "fooCookie" ) );
```

... the value is always the string **${COOKIE_FOO}** as if the dollar/curly bracket notation is not being parsed.

I feel like I must be missing something painfully obvious here, but after several hours of fighting this, I am bringing it to the experts.  Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: Adding a bit more detail.  This is the layout of my test plan

```
Test Plan
    User Defined Variables
    HTTP Cookie Manager
    HTTP Request Defaults
    Login Thread (setup)
        [page request - login POST]
            HTTP Header Manager
            BeanShell PostProcessor
        [more page requests]
```

And I do indeed have **CookieManager.save.cookies=true** set in the jmeter.bat file that I am launching it with.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `HTTP Cookie Manager` in your test plan? If not, you need to have that.
You also need to set the `CookieManager.save.cookies=true` in the jmeter.properties file which you can find in JMETER_HOME/bin folder.

`${COOKIE_FOO}` will return the actual cookie value.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I do indeed have those things and I have updated my post to give that detail.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your `${COOKIE_FOO}` variable is really set using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination. Your code is OK so my expectation is that the variable is not set.
2. Those who suggest using Beanshell where it is possible to handle the situation using JMeter built-in test elements should probably consider quitting IT. There are:

   - [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function to put something to JMeter Properties
   - [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and/or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function to read something from them

See [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) guide for real-life example.